# element.onchange not working for a list of element

Tags: javascript, events

So I have a class two class named "Form" and "Question". "Form" contained an array of Question.
When I add a question in the array, I call a method called render() in each question

```
    render() {
        let htmlElement = document.getElementById("formBody");

        let id = Question.GenerateID();
        htmlElement.innerHTML += `
                <div class="p-2">
                    <input type="text" class="input-transparent w-100" id="${id}.t" value="${this.Title}" placeholder="Unnamed question">
                </div>`;

        /**
         * @param {int} id
         */
        let questionNameChange = function(id) {
            this.Title = document.getElementById(id + ".t").value;
        };

        document.getElementById(id + ".t").onchange = questionNameChange.bind(this, id);
     }
```

Image of the form

[image: Image of the form]

The problem is that the element.onchange, which allows me to change the title of a question.

When I change the title of any questions, via the input text, it only works on the last question that has been rendered.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Do you have more than one element with that ID?

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `.` in IDs. You won't be able to refer to that ID in a CSS selector, since `.` is used to select a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have to delay binding the onchange until the element has been inserted in the dom. In other words, wrap it in a setTimeout:

```
  setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById(id + ".t").onchange = questionNameChange.bind(this, id);
  })
```

Check out this working example:

```js
let Question = {GenerateID: () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}
class MyClass {
  constructor(){
    this.Title = 'my title'
  }
  
  questionNameChange(id) {
    this.Title = document.getElementById(id + ".t").value;
    document.getElementById(`${id}-label`).innerHTML = this.Title
  }

  render() {
        let htmlElement = document.getElementById("formBody");

        let id = Question.GenerateID();
        htmlElement.innerHTML += `
                <div class="p-2">
                    <input type="text" class="input-transparent w-100" id="${id}.t" value="${this.Title}" placeholder="Unnamed question">
                    <label id="${id}-label"></label>
                </div>`;

        setTimeout(() => {
          document.getElementById(id + ".t").onchange = () => {
            this.questionNameChange(id)
          }
        })
        
  }   
}

$(() => {     
  let myClass = new MyClass()
     myClass.render()
     myClass.render()
     myClass.render()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="formBody">

</form>
```

Comment: Works! Thank you!

Comment: It shouldn't matter if the element is in the DOM or not.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Assigning to `.innerHTML` inserts it into the DOM. You seem to be suggesting that this is asynchronous, but it isn't.

Comment: If it didn't add it to the DOM, it would get an error because `document.getElementById(id + ".t")` would return `null`.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. it's because it's using `innerHTML +=`. This re-renders all the HTML of the element, and that discards all the old event handlers.

Comment: This isn't really a complete solution. It will only work for all the elements added in this loop, the elements that were added earlier will lose their listeners. See the duplicate question I just linked to for the proper solution.